# Converting RadioButtlonList Item to Boolean for entry to Database via LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am attempting to read items from local RadiobuttonList items and take them as Boolean values and insert them to my database.

The problem the thread keeps getting aborted and I am not sure where I am going wrong. So I was wondering if could have some help troubleshooting this issue.

I have a method that reads in the Radiobuttonlist and should check if the Yes option is selected and outputs whether a true or false:

```
    private Boolean checkRB(RadioButtonList list)
    {
        Boolean value;

        if (list.SelectedItem.Text == "Yes")
        {
            value = true;
        }
        else
        {
            value = false;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Next here is the line that i am using to insert the item to the database:

```
    table rea = new table();
    rea.another_inst = checkRB(rbAnotherInst);
```

Could anyone help me with trouble shooting this?

Comment: Your method can be refactored to `return list.SelectedItem.Text == "Yes"`

Comment: Why/how is your thread being aborted? Is it timing out? Can you please copy/paste the specific name of the exception and the message?

Comment: I think your code couldn't be compiled because the variable `value` is not assigned (Any declared variable should be assigned with some value except data members in a class,struct).

Comment: Do you have an exception being thrown? Also some context would be helpful. Lastly `if(list.SelectedItem.Text' =="Yes")` should probably be null checked like this `if(list.SelectedItem != null && list.SelectedItem.Text == "Yes")`

Comment: It doesnt give me the specific exception unfortunately, it just says thread aborted. I am not sure what you mean. @Ringer I just made that change and I still got the same thing

Comment: You are getting this message running the debugger?  How did you deduce that this is where the problem is occurring? Posting the calling code would be helpful, what you have posted here doesn't give much context in which to solve your problem.

Comment: I added this line in my code:  Response.Write(oe.InnerException);   Response.End(); And got the error. I got have been testing to figure where the problem started and added the line: rea.another_inst = checkRB(rbAnotherInst); then the error start @ringer

Comment: @Ringer i finally got the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Paradigm I'm still not clear if you are using the VS debugger or not. If you are, having break on exception set in your debugger preferences will cause execution to stop at the offending null reference. Then it is only a matter of making sure that object is properly initialized before you attempt to use it. So the next step is for you to figure out what is throwing the exception. But at least you are one step closer.

Answer (score 2):

From your comment: "I added this line in my code: Response.Write(oe.InnerException); Response.End(); And got the error."

Why do you call `Response.End()`? `Response.End()` triggers a `ThreadAbortException` by design:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629

Comment: It actually just goes along as if nothing happened when I dont do the respond.end(). I wasnt sure how else to get it to publish the error

Comment: Did alot on this and got the actual error now: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I'm afraid you've included far too little information to assist in debugging this. Take a look at this link to help form a more defined question: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx